# How to check a specific type of tuple or list?

Tags: python, types, tuples, isinstance

Suppose,

```
var = ('x', 3)
```

How to check if a variable is a tuple with only two elements, first being a type str and the other a type int in python?
Can we do this using only one check?
I want to avoid this -

```
if isinstance(var, tuple):
    if isinstance (var[0], str) and (var[1], int):
         return True
return False
```

Comment: What do you mean by only one check? As in one line?

Comment: @idjaw, I think the OP means without checking each part individually.

Comment: `[type(e) for e in var] == [str, int]` may be

Comment: You can write your own function that checks the type (recursively) e.g. `istype(var, ('x', 3))`. It's as clean as it gets.

Comment: `return all(map(isinstance, zip(var, (str,int))))` does not seem any more readable than your explicit checks

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple one-liner:

```
isinstance(v, tuple) and list(map(type, v)) == [str, int]
```

Try it out:

```
>>> def check(v):
        return isinstance(v, tuple) and list(map(type, v)) == [str, int]
...
>>> check(0)
False
>>> check(('x', 3, 4))
False
>>> check((3, 4))
False
>>> check(['x', 3])
False
>>> check(('x', 3))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you ask for, but you might find it useful.

```
from itertools import izip_longest


def typemap(iterable, types, *indexes):
    # izip_longest helps with the length check, because we will get a TypeError if len(iterable) > len(types)
    try:
        _iterable = ((elem for ind, elem in enumerate(iterable)
                     if ind in indexes) if indexes else iterable)
        return all(isinstance(elem, _type)
                   for elem, _type in izip_longest(_iterable, types))
    except TypeError:
        return False

typemap((1, 2, "ch", {}, []), (int, int, str, dict, list)) # -> True
typemap((1, 2, "ch", {}, []), (int, int, str, dict)) # -> False
typemap((1, 2, "ch", {}, []), (int, int, str, list), 0, 1, 2, 4) # -> True
```

Comment: This gets my vote for generality, except you definitely do need a `try ... except` around it to catch the case of `iterable` not being iterable.

Comment: you don't need `izip_longest`, just check the len, you also don't check the actual element passed in.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It was there in the first version, but I didn't like that it required you to build a list of `bool`s or something in memory in case `iterable` was a generator. And I prefer staying lazy even when it has little practical meaning.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, true, what could make it more general is allowing to pick the indexes to check using itemgetter.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for suggestion. I've implemented it without `itemgetter`, because it requires `__getitem__`, and standard generators don't have the method.

Comment: Yep, probably better actually as it will lazily evaluate, the set will be costly though as it will be recreated each iteration but if someone is using the function I doubt there will be a lot of data. If anyone wanted to use itemgetter it is just a matter of ` _iterable = itemgetter(*indexes)(iterable)`

Answer (score 0):

Well considering tuples are variable in length you're not going to find a method that checks this instance of all it's types. What's wrong with the method you have? It's clear what it does and it fits your usage. You're not going to find a pretty one liner AFAIK.

And you do have a one liner... Technically:

```
def isMyTuple(my_tuple):
    return isinstance(my_tuple,(tuple, list)) and isinstance(my_tuple[0],str) and isinstance(my_tuple[1],int)

var = ('x', 3)

print isMyTuple(var)
```

If you're going to do this check many times, calling the method is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Comment: Your original answer was nothing like it is now.

Comment: I'm allowed to improve my answer

Comment: Not really, it explains why a method call is needed to be DRY

Comment: What has DRY got to do with anything? The OP is using a function so what is the difference?

Comment: I was emphasizing DRYs importance.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain all your ifs on one line:

```
result = isinstance(var, tuple) and isinstance(var[0], str) and isinstance(var[1], int)
```

`result` will be True is all conditions match, else it'll be False

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a tuple of arguments to isinstance to test for a list or a tuple:

```
def test(t):
    return  isinstance(t, (tuple, list))and len(t) == 2 and\
        isinstance(t[0], str) and isinstance(t[1], int)
```

If you only want to accept either lists or tuples with two elements you need the check for the length, if it did not have to be 2 you would still need to make sure it had at least two elements to avoid an indexError

Comment: I would put first the tuple check and then the len check, no?

Comment: @Apero,  true, could get passed something that would gawk on the length check

Comment: I'd use the [`Sequence` ABC](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) instead of `(tuple, list)`.

Answer (score -1):

You could go down the route of begging forgiveness:

```
def isMyTuple( var):
    try:
        return isinstance(var, tuple) and \
               isinstance (var[0], str) and \
               isinstance(var[1], int)
    except:
        return False
```

I'm not entirely certain you need the `try ... except` in this case. Python uses short-circult logic. If it's not a tuple the second and third tests don't get executed and so you don't crash out trying to index a non-indexable var. But just possibly, someone derived a class from Tuple and modified it so its indexes aren't integers, or some other wierdness.

BTW should you should also check len(var)==2 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own function that checks if a variable matches a specification:

```
def istype(var, spec):
    if type(var) != type(spec):
        return False
    if isinstance(spec, tuple):
        if len(var) != len(spec):
            return False
        return all([istype(var[i], spec[i]) for i in range(len(var))])
    return True
```

You have to add more checks for other types, but for your example this will suffice.

```
>>> istype((1,'x'), (2,'y'))
True
```

Comment: using a list comp with all rather defeats the purpose

Comment: Exactly what my answer

Comment: If by purpose you mean efficiency, then... yes. It won't short circuit. It's still clean code though.

Comment: @JeffreyHaines: huh??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath,not me, I got one for my trouble too. I would still use a gen exp

Comment: as did I. lots of people going for the answer I guess

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: ??

Comment: Try this: `l = []; l.append(l); istype(l, l)`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: Not sure there's a point of handling it, I mean, sending that recursive structure *as* specification is just silly.