# How to check if a variable is an instance of my custom data type in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do a type check of a variable against my custom variable. How to achieve something like below,

```
Predicate = Tuple[str, str , str]
LogicalPredicate = Tuple[Predicate, str, Predicate]
my_var = ('age', 'is', 'null')
if isinstance(my_var, Predicate):
  #do something
else if isinstance(my_var, LogicalPredicate):
  #do something else
else:
  raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing library is mainly used for type hints and improving readability, so the syntax `Tuple[str, str, str]` is a class meta rather than a type.
To check if `my_var` has the right format with `isinstance` you need a slightly different syntax:

```
Predicate = type(('','',''))
LogicalPredicate = type((Predicate, '', Predicate))
```

This then should work with `isinstance()`

**EDIT**

As kindly pointed out, the above returns True for all Tuple instances; to check the elements within the Tuple one more step is required to test `Predicate`:

```
tuple(map(type, my_var)) == (str, str, str)
```

to check logical predicate more conditions need to be added (so worth considering converting this to a method) but overall:

```
my_var = ('age', 'is', 'null')
if isinstance(my_var, tuple) and  tuple(map(type, my_var)) == (str, str, str):
    print('Predicate')
elif isinstance(my_var, tuple) and tuple(map(type, my_var[0])) == (str, str, str) and tuple(map(type, my_var[2])) == (str, str, str) and isinstance(my_var[1], str):
    print('LogicalPredicate')
else:
    raise ValueError
```

Similar explanations can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770725/how-to-check-a-specific-type-of-tuple-or-list)

Comment: Thanks @nickthefreak for responsing. I tried running the code, but the `isinstance()` passed `True` even if `myvar` did not follow the format `('','','')`.

Comment: interesting! I think the issue is that it's True as long as it is a tuple. Let me research more and come back with a correction (or deletion of the answer)